# GTM Custom HTML x26

Tags: google-tag-manager

When uploading the script below as Custom HTML in GTM

I've noticed that the & changes to \x26 and = to \x3d - Wondering how to upload the above script and keeping special characters.

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
function loadScript(url, callback){
var script = document.createElement("script")
script.type = "text/javascript";
if (script.readyState){ //IE
script.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete"){ script.onreadystatechange = null; callback(); }
};
} else { //Others
script.onload = function(){ callback(); };
}
script.src = url;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
loadScript("https://pro.pocketmath.com/js/pmct_conversion.js", function(){__PMCT_CE_CONVERSION.init("&ce=49c6fc104f5d_10&awin=ct30")});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add a description (or better yet, a screenshot) of where you see them changed?